# Specifying variable in Python

Tags: python, int32

I am making an TF2 backpack viewer in Python, and I have inventory token that is an 32 unsigned long. First 16 bits are unimportant for me. Usual approach in C would be something like

```
(a<<16)>>16
```

to get last 16 bits. But Python is no C, and it above operation will not work. How do I specify that Python SHOULD use int32 for this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bitwise AND operator (`&`):

```
>>> 0x12345678 & 0xffff
22136
>>> hex(_)
'0x5678'
```

Comment: @RomaValcer, See [`Bitwise operation - AND` wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)

```
array.array('H', [10])
```

Will create array of 1 unsigned short word. (Several years ago I've written a HW driver in Python combining [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) and [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)